# Custom action links in .PDF...write Javascript to alter the appearance of links when clicked?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a .pdf document that contains custom links which run Javascript code.

There is no issue with the actual functionality of the working portion of the JS, but I do have one formatting/display problem that I havent been able to solve:

Is it possible to write JS that will alter the appearance of individual links as they are clicked?

I know I can programmatically change the appearance of *all* links on a page by looping through the doc.getLinks result and applying formatting changes to each element of the getLinks array. But I don't know how to refer to a *specific* link, as/after it's clicked, either by referencing that link's index location within the getLinks array, or by referring to it by any other name, handle, etc.

I would think that this is probably possible to do, but I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

---

EDIT: One thing to clarify...I can do everything I need to do for a single button. That is, I can manually find the button name, and manually enter the JS code to change the appearance of that particular button. To do this, I need to physically look up the name of the button using a few mouse clicks, and then hard code that button's name in my JS getField command. This requires different code for each and every button.

Is it possible to accomplish the same function using *the same code* for each and every button?

My ultimate objective is to be able to reproduce this function on a series of .pdf files that will, jointly, have thousands of individual buttons. So any manual component of this process will make implementation impractical.

I should have originally phrased the question in terms of, *is it possible to write JS code that can automatically detect the name of the button which is calling the code*? (ie, how would I implement a self-referential feature for a generic button?)

Comment: Links are too simple; use Buttons instead.

Comment: Thanks, @MaxWyss I am looking into this now.

Comment: @MaxWyss I do see and appreciate the richer set of options available by using buttons rather than links as the interactive object here, but I'm still having the same core problem, it seems. I do not know how to programmatically refer to the properties of a specific button, within the code that executes when that specific button is clicked.

Comment: You might look at the event object in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation. And, yes, the field object concerned is normally event.target

Comment: @MaxWyss YESSSS!!!! Thank you for that! You can't believe how helpful that is. Many, many thanks. :)

Comment: @MaxWyss If you would like to re-post the event.target information as an answer, I would happy to accept it right away. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wished by the OP…

When a script should refer to the field on which it is running, the field object to use is `event.target`.

An example:

You have a button which, when clicked, should change the width of the border between 1 and 3. The mouseUp event would containt this piece of code:

```
if (event.target.lineWidth == 1) {
event.target.lineWidth = 3 ;
} else {
event.target.lineWidth = 1 ;
}
```

Or another example: when the number in the calculated text field is negative, it should be in red, otherwise in black:

In the Format event of that field, you would add:

```
if (event.value*1 < 0) {
event.target.textColor = color.red ;
} else {
event.target.textColor = color.black ;
}
```

And that should give an idea on how to use event.target.